# Pass a variable String to a function

Tags: c, string, function, dynamic, parameters

How can I pass a variable String, i.e, one that changes during run-time to a function as a parameter?

For example function `foo(char * string)` takes a string pointer parameter to do something with it. The following loop is uses the above function:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  foo("String"+i);
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is `+i` trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @Mostack It is unclear what is the problem and what the function does.

Comment: What do you think your code doesn't achieve?  The only problem I see is that you've declared `foo(char *string)` but you've passed a pointer to constant data that should not be modified.  Either use `void foo(const char *string)` or arrange to use something other than a string literal (e.g. `char data[] = "String";` and call `foo(data + i);`.

Comment: Just add it to the sample String. So, I would like to pass "String <value of i>" as the loop increments.

Comment: Have a look at the duplicate post I linked.  You need to solve two problems: 1.  How to convert your int value into a string, and 2.  How to concatenate your passed in string with the string of your int value.

Comment: That sounds like a case for `snprintf()` —— `char buffer[16]; for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "String %d", i); foo(buffer); }`.  C does not provide string primitives like scripting languages do.  Using `foo("String" + i)` passes the pointer to the `S`, then to the `t`, then to the `r`, … as `i` increases from 0.

Comment: Oof.  I have some bad news for you.  This isn't Python.  Robert's link is probably what you are looking for.  Just for clarifications sake, `char*` is not a pointer to a string.  It's a pointer to some bytes.  We may say a bunch of bytes the ends in a null terminator (zero byte), is a string, but there is no native string in C.

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Thanks, @JonathanLeffler